# Support iPhone 4 and iPad 1 but not iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect, ipod-touch

We want our game to support these devices:

- iPod Touch 4th Gen and up
- iPhone4 and up
- All iPads

We don't want to support 3GS because it is a game with lots of graphic detail and we think the experience is subpar in 3GS. We don't want to drop support for iPad 1. We want the App Store to enforce this (not within the app itself).

I think [we cannot achieve this](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/05/02/how-to-indicate-what-devices-are-supported-by-your-ios-app) through [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html).

Is there any possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible at all for *universal apps*. Either you enable both *iPhone 3GS* and *iPad 1* or none.